how to provide the device name that related to LVM2_member
LVM2_member could be different according to device partition number
example
 lsblk -f | grep     LVM2_member   | awk '{print $1}'
└─sda3

or on other redhat machine
 lsblk -f | grep  LVM2_member  | awk '{print $1}'
└─sda2             

how to capture sdaX device without the line "└─" , or maybe other approach to capture OS device that related to LVM2_member
view from lsblk -f
    lsblk -f
    NAME             FSTYPE      LABEL                  UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
    sda
    ├─sda1           vfat                               E7D6-EC08                              /boot/efi
    ├─sda2           xfs                                1d74a8b2-9226-45cf-aa90-f9c9783a9a57   /boot
    └─sda3           LVM2_member                        eRpqzd-o7UM-ruPb-2xU3-QUAW-EswH-PzsSZE
      ├─VG00-lvv_root xfs                                e0cfac88-be2e-41e4-8163-da3ef0fcb98c   /
      ├─VG00-lvv_swap swap                               91341494-85f3-4300-9f66-68922c39418b   [SWAP]
      └─VG00-lvv_var  xfs                                92cc4e1a-23a4-40ac-ae5d-b0d884bfdeeb   /var


if your lsblk version has json output
lsblk -J -o NAME,FSTYPE | jq '.. | select(.fstype? == "LVM2_member")' 
{
  "name": "sda3",
  "fstype": "LVM2_member"
}

to get the name only
lsblk -J -o NAME,FSTYPE | jq -r '.. | select(.fstype? == "LVM2_member") | .name'

sda3

